# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException grails

Tags: database, grails, groovy

I have this simple controller which uploads a file into the database. I have a working view which displays the form for uploading, but when I click on the upload button, I run into this error at the `documentInstance.save()` line: **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request:[POST]/myApp/documentFile/upload**

```
class DocumentController {
    def upload() {
        def file = request.getFile('file')
        if(file.empty) {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        } else {
            def documentInstance = new Document()
            documentInstance.filename = file.originalFilename
            documentInstance.filedata = file.getBytes()
            documentInstance.save()
        }
        redirect (action:'list')
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand where the problem lies? Is the information I have given sufficient for answering this? If not please let me know.

**UPDATE:**

form element part of the gsp is as below.

```
           <g:uploadForm action="upload">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="upload" class="save" value="Upload" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:uploadForm>
```

Here is the `Document` domain class

```
class Document{

    String filename
    byte[] fileData

    static constraints = {
        filename(blank:false,nullable:false)
        filedata(blank: true, nullable:true, maxSize:1073741824)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part (form element) of the GSP.

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant GSP code.

Comment: also the full stacktrace would help

Comment: also the `Document` domain class definition...

Comment: Have you tried forcing the encoding to a specific character set? Something like `.getBytes("UTF8")`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  'size' or 'maxSize' constraints on your domain objects 'filedata' field according to the size of the files you are uploading. Your database might be creating small columns that cannot hold the file size you are uploading. According to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles